# UFT is waiting the entire object sync timeout before clicking a webelement

Tags: hp-uft

Alright, in my web application there's a dropdown that UFT picks up as a 'WebElement' instead of a 'WebList'. The options available in this dropdown are all just 'divs' and the data within the div is dynamic. Has anyone had to deal with this before? I even tried using the absolute xpath within the object repository, but that seems to be inconsistent. Whenever I run my test the first time it interacts with the dropdown it will wait the entire object sync timeout before selecting the element. Then I have it going back to select another item from the dropdown and it goes instantly. This isn't the approach I want to take with this as the abs xpath could break at any time. I've been reading blog posts etc from as far back as 2008, and tried every person's suggestion but I can't reliably click a dropdown and select something. I can give more detail if needed, but any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When UFT waits the object synchronization timeout and then succeeds to perform the action it's usually because it has been using [smart identification](https://www.learnqtp.com/how-qtp-identifies-objects-complete-refresher/). Look in the report to see if this is the case (or just disable smart identification and see what happens).

If this is the case, you should try to fine-tune the description to succeed on the description and not resort to smart identification.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! This behaviour was being caused by the 'browser' being different in that part of my code. I think this happened due to some of the same items being added into the OR from different pages.

Instead of having:
Browser("Browser1").Page("Page1").WebElement("Element I want").
It was:
Browser("Browser2").Page("Page1").WebElement("Element I want").

Once this was corrected in the OR everything worked as expected.